# Riddle of how to set ChartArea Y-axis Min-Max values with user input from textboxes

Tags: c#, charts, textbox

I have a chart on WinForm application which shows several line type of series.
But the points on the Y-axis of the series, values only change by 1 along to X-Axis. So in order to remove empty-unused space from Y-Axis, i put 2 textbox to give user ability to change Min-Max values of it and make values of Y-Axis seen more detailed.

But this manual change of axis min-max values brings a riddle which i couldn't solve completely.

I understand, in order to have program not to crash;
+ program should check if the Y-min, Y-max textboxes are empty,
+ program should check if entered values are actually doubles, not strings,
+ program should check if the entered or current Y-max value is bigger than entered or current Y-min value,
+ program should check if the entered or current Y-max value is smaller than entered or current Y-max value.

I have tried several approaches but couldn't solve this riddle completely.
Here is one version;

```
 private void BtnBenchApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   double yMin = 0;
   double yMax = 0;
   double n;

   if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtYmin.Text)) && double.TryParse(txtYmin.Text, out n) == true)
        {
            yMin = double.Parse(txtYmin.Text);
        }
   if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtYmax.Text)) && double.TryParse(txtYmax.Text, out n) == true)
        {
            yMax = double.Parse(txtYmax.Text);
        }

   else
        {
            if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtYmax.Text)) && (yMax <= yMin))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please check Min-Max values!", "Invalid Action", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }

            else
            {
                chartBench.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = yMax;
                chartBench.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = yMin;
            }
        }    
    }
```

How can i implement this conditions to code in order to have program not to crash?

Comment: What crash do you experience? Also: Why bother ? The default will automatically adapt the chartarea to make best use of the space. - Also: I would parse out the values and only then do the checks and finally set the values. It is hard to follow as it is. Did you use the debugger to see what branches your code executes? Also: The 1st condition seems to be all wrong. (Replace `&&` by `||`  or pull in the `!` to both expressions!)

Comment: With this code piece, if the Y-max textbox empty, program gets into messagebox if, and doesn't apply the min value change. And chartarea is not adapted automatically, although all Y-axis values are between let's say 144-146, automatic value given for Y-max is 160 and automatic Y-min value is -20. If i could make it automatically adapt to series min-max values, i would take it. how can i do that?

Comment: It happens by default but if you have somewhere set numbers to axis.Minimum etc you can reset it like so: `axis.Minimum = double.NaN`.. - Also: The code as posted is badly formatted and thus very hard to follow. The `else` belong to the 2nd `if` and the 1st `if has no `else` . The indentation says otherwise.. Do check for typos!

Comment: Sorry about the code adjustment. i saw that later on, after i posted it. So if i call `axis.Minimum = double.NaN` after series are defined for the chart, it will adapt the Y-Axis? (and the `axis.Maximum= double.NaN` of course)

Comment: Why not instead of a text box, just use the actual values of what you are charting? Keep the lowest and highest values on the y-axis from your series and set your yMin and yMax from that.

Comment: Yes, that should reset to the default 'automatic' setting.